# phpmyadmin installed successfully but doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, server, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed PHPMyAdmin on ubuntu 14.04 successfully but I cannot access the interface. I mean `http://mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin` is this:

[image]

Why it isn’t working and how can I fix the problem?

Noted that I installed PHPMyAdmin by following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: If you see a "500 error" the very first thing you do is check your error log. If you can't find that, then you go looking. There's any number of things that could have gone wrong here, we can't even begin to guess, but once you dig up an error we can probably set you in the right direction.

Comment: @tadman Ah .. ok I will take a look at error log. And one thing, can you please take a look at my server if I give you user and password? You know, I have to launch my project in 10 hours and everything is working on local. The only problem is phpmyadmin doesn't work on the server.. `:-(`

Comment: If you need mentoring, coaching or emergency support try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: @tadman ok thank you.

Comment: 500 is server error, checkout apache logs

Comment: After checking the log file, probably you will find missing required PHP module or miss configured file. However, you have to be sure that PHP is recording errors in the log file first.

Comment: guys where is log file placed ? (ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @stack alternatively you can use "Adminer". No need to install it. Just upload a single file and complete your work.

https://www.adminer.org/

Comment: In your case I think it will be the log file of your Apache's default host, which is specified in the default host config `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` @stack

Comment: I think this is not the best place to inquire about this issue. Please check [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)